# xsl sort and number

Tags: xml, xslt

I've never used XSL before, so pretty sure there is an easy answer for this but I'm having trouble. I'm trying to take my input and output a numbered list of items, but I'm trying to sort the items before numbering them. I'm either getting numbering without the sorting, or the sorting is working but numbering is out of order. I did some copy/pasting, but removed a fair amount of content for brevity, I think all the relevant portions are there.

```
<workitem id="9421" type="Feature" state="Development">     
    <System.Id>9421</System.Id>
    <System.WorkItemType>Feature</System.WorkItemType>
    <workitem id="9404" type="Bug" state="Development">
        <System.Id>9404</System.Id>
        <System.WorkItemType>Bug</System.WorkItemType>
    </workitem>
    <workitem id="9422" type="User Story" state="Development">
        <System.Id>9422</System.Id>
        <System.WorkItemType>User Story</System.WorkItemType>
    </workitem>
    <workitem id="9423" type="User Story" state="Development">
        <System.Id>9423</System.Id>
        <System.WorkItemType>User Story</System.WorkItemType>
    </workitem>
    <workitem id="9424" type="User Story" state="Development">
        <System.Id>9424</System.Id>
        <System.WorkItemType>User Story</System.WorkItemType>
    </workitem>
    <workitem id="9431" type="Bug" state="Development">
        <System.Id>9431</System.Id>
        <System.WorkItemType>Bug</System.WorkItemType>
    </workitem>
</workitem>
```

And here is an example of the xsl relevant to that portion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/result /workitem" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="workitem[@type='Feature']">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
  <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(System.WorkItemType,' ','')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />
     #<xsl:value-of select="System.Id" />
  </xsl:element >
  <xsl:apply-templates select="workitem">
      <xsl:sort select="@type" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem[@type='Bug']">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
  <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(System.WorkItemType,' ','')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />
    #<xsl:value-of select="System.Id" />
  </xsl:element >
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem[@type='User Story']">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
  <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(System.WorkItemType,' ','')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />
    #<xsl:value-of select="System.Id" />
  </xsl:element >
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get with that is this:

> 1. Feature #9421
>      1.1. Bug #9404
>      1.5. Bug #9431
>      1.2. User Story #9422
>      1.3. User Story #9423
>      1.4. User Story #9424

What I want:

> 1. Feature #9421
>      1.1. Bug #9404
>      1.2. Bug #9431
>      1.3. User Story #9422
>      1.4. User Story #9423
>      1.5. User Story #9424

Any words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:number` will return the position of the current element in the input XML, regardless of how you have selected it or trying to sort it. If you want to find the position after the sort you should use `position()`

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), '. ')" />
```

However, you will have to do a little bit extra work in the second template, as you will need to pass in the position of the parent `workItem` as a parameter to allow you to get the full number

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/result/workitem">
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem[@type='Feature']">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
  <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(System.WorkItemType,' ','')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), '. ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />
     #<xsl:value-of select="System.Id" />
  </xsl:element>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="workitem">
      <xsl:with-param name="parentPos" select="position()" />
      <xsl:sort select="@type" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem[@type='Bug' or @type='User Story']">
  <xsl:param name="parentPos"/>
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
  <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(System.WorkItemType,' ','')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($parentPos, '.', position(), '. ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />
    #<xsl:value-of select="System.Id" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, you might like to know you can do automatic numbering of the child list using CSS counters, rather than try to do it in XSLT.

Try this too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".") ". ";
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    display:inline;
}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/result/workitem" />
    </body>      
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem[@type='Feature']">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(System.WorkItemType,' ','')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" /> #<xsl:value-of select="System.Id" />
      </xsl:element>
      <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="workitem">
          <xsl:sort select="@type" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem[@type='Bug' or @type='User Story']">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
  <li>
    <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(System.WorkItemType,' ','')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />  #<xsl:value-of select="System.Id" />
    </xsl:element>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The css solution was perfect, thank you. Also, thanks for the extra bit on the or statement in the match, figured there was a way to do something like that, just didn't have time to find it.